# Windows toolbar is ignored when maximizing

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

For the last couple of days I have the following problem on my XP machine.

When I maximize a window, it fills up my entire screen, including the Windows taskbar. I've unsuccessfully tried the following;

- Reboot my PC
- Relocate/resize my taskbar

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that your task bar is no longer set "always on top". Here's how to fix it:

1. Right Click on an empty spot of the taskbar and select properties.
2. Ensure that that "Keep taskbar on top of other windows" check box is checked.

As shown in this image:

[image]